# stage.addEventListener inside a package?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to do something like this:

```
package com.clicker{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Stager extends MovieClip {

        public function clicker():void {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, do_stage);
        }
        function do_stage(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("stage clicked");
        }

    }
}
```

But, I get the 1009 error.

When I do this:

```
import com.clicker.*;

var test:Stager = new Stager();
test.clicker();
addChild(test);
```

Please help me. Thank you very much in advance, and Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 8):

stage is accessible only when your component is added to the stage. If you want to know it, you can use the ADDED_TO_STAGE event.

So, you can do this :

```
package com.clicker{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Stager extends MovieClip {

        public function clicker():void {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, do_stage);
        }
        function do_stage(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("stage clicked");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you  call `test.clicker();` before it added to the stage `test` doesn't  have a this.stage object yet  try :

```
public class Stager extends MovieClip {

    public function clicker():void {
       this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE , function(ev:Event) {
             stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, do_stage);
       });

    }
    function do_stage(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("stage clicked");
    }
```

}

hope this helps...