# Hide Adobe Flash player setting dialog using flex

Tags: apache-flex, webcam, flash

In my web apllication i loaded camera using flex. when open camera it displays adobe flash player setting dialog box for user accept or deny. I want to open camera with out asking to user(without dialog) i have to capture user automatically when user login to our site. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. Can you imagine what could happen if any web site could access your camera w/out your permission?

The only way to prevent the dialog from appearing is to have the user accept it once, and click the "remember" option.

If you try to access the camera without doing anything, the user will see a simple dialog with only "Allow" and "Deny" options.

However, you can trigger the "Privacy" dialog that has an option to remember the "Allow" or "Deny" for future sessions:

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
```

When you do this, it shows a different panel that has the option to remember the setting so they next time they visit your site they won't get the dialog at all (provided they clicked "Allow" the first time). A lot of websites like to orchestrate this process, so that this dialog is displayed before they try to access the camera.

Then, they use [this well known hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945055/flash-security-settings-panel-listening-for-close-event) to know when the dialog is closed, and then access the camera. Note that page has a lesser known hack that is a much cleaner solution, I've never tried it, but I recommend you do if you go this route.