# Adobe Flash Player Settings Javascript close event

Tags: javascript, flash

Are any events triggered when the close settings button is click in the Adobe Flash Player Settings window. I want to be able to move the containing div when the settings are closed.

Comment: There is no such event. Have a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945055/flash-security-settings-panel-listening-for-close-event).

Answer (score -1):

Decided to go with a lame solution find if the click event within the containing div is located within the coordinates of the close button.

Far from perfect but will do for now...