# Flash Object to small for Security "Window"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, overflow, visibility

I have made a flash as3 project in adobe flash pro with the dimensions 20px x 150px.

i would like to ceep it this size, but the problem is that my application needs to ask for the MICROPHONE premissions

( like in the image )

[image]

but this only happens if the flash object is big enough.

are there any workarounds with maybe the "overflow = visible" method or something ?

thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

1. Temporarily increase the dimensions of the SWF in HTML. I've never done this, but I imagine it would work and is the most simplest solution.
2. Use `wmode="transparent"` or `wmode="opaque"` in your embed code. In both of these modes you can layer HTML on top of or underneath the Flash object. The SWF should be sized so that it is big enough to display the dialog. When the dialog is not visible, you can hide portions of the Flash app by covering them with HTML.

I've used the 2nd option successfully, not for this purpose, but for showing some HTML elements (arrow images and text) to guide the user through these "allow" camera/microphone dialogs.

For both of these options to work, you need to be able to detect when the user has closed the dialog. Though there is no official Flash API for doing this, however, there are some [good work arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9275935/398606) for doing that.

Comment: alright thx, i already had the windowmode set to transparent. but i think i'll just leave the dimensions ( insode flash ) by around 250 x 200 ( thats a goot even size where the security window is showing up ).

Comment: ( btw: if you're showing up the ( extensive ) security dialog with `Security.showSettings( SecurityPanel.MICROPHONE )` then you can be shure that after this line, the security window was clicked ( either "allow" or "deny" )