# How to Detect Settings Opening/Closing in a ContextMenu in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm working with a [ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) and I was able to locate the [events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ContextMenuEvent.html) for detecting when a selection is made, however I want to detect when the "Settings" menu item in particular is *closed*. How could I go about this? I'm currently embedding iframes in the flex application and I want to hide them until the menu is closed.

The culprit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6946565/474947) should help.

It is a workaround, but I think it is the best we can do for now.

- When you detect menuItemSelect event, add enterFrame event handler
- In the event handler, check if `BitmapData.draw(stage)` throws an error.
- If it stops throwing error, then remove the enterFrame handler and do what you want: set iframe to visible.